# I am trying to integrate the Berry curvature of Dirac Semimetal to obtain anomalous hall conductivity

Tags: condensed-matter, topology, quantum-hall-effect

$$\Omega_{ij}(k)^{\pm} = \frac{v^2cos(\theta)\left(b\pm\frac{vk_z^2}{\sqrt{k_y^2\sin^2(\theta) +k_z^2}}\right)}{4\left(v^2k_x^2+v^2k_y^2cos^2(\theta)+\left( b\pm v\sqrt{k_y^2\sin^2(\theta) +k_z^2}\right)^2)\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$
$$\sigma_{ij}=\frac{e^2}{h2\pi^3}\int d^3k \Omega_{ij}(k)$$
where $\sigma_{ij}$ is the anomalous Hall conductivity. The integration is over the Brillouin zone. The anomalous Hall conductivity turns out to be
$$\sigma_{ij} = \frac{e^2b}{v\pi}sgn(cos(\theta))$$
How to solve the above integration?
This is the [link](https://journals.aps.org/prb/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevB.99.075116) to the paper in which the above calculations are done. I have not been able to solve this particular integral.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried to do the integral in this case. But usually these topological things boil down to writing the hamiltonian in the form $d_x\sigma_x+d_y\sigma_y+d_z\sigma_z$ and then computing (by simply looking at the formula)  the winding number of the map $\hat {\bf d}:{\rm Brillouin{\phantom i}zone} \to S^2$ where $\hat {\bf d}$ is the unit vector in the direction ${\bf d}$.  There should be  no need to actually *do* the integration.

In you case you have both $\sigma$'s and $\tau$'s, and a three-d integral so the connection between Chern number and winding number is a bit more complicated, but it should still exist.